# Website as Application - browse issue after some time

Tags: reactjs, safari, upload

This is very strange. I have a website that I have asked my users to add as Home application to their phones. everything is perfect, except the upload stops working after some time. The only way to fix is to Close and reopen the whole app (web) again.

1. I noticed the action happens, if you imagine the box is under it, it will go to your galery. so looks like the box does not show up after some time.
2. why this happens?
3. how can I fix it so you do not need to reopen it?
4. mostly happens in Safari which is added to the Home as an app.